# How to use User's input as the value of a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I just downloaded Cordova to my Visual Studio 2015, and I decided to create a really simple app in which the app ask you your name, and uses that information given to him to give them as a value of a variable which will then proceed to use it to creat a certain "Hello World" which instead will say "Hello (Name of the user)."

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can using DOM (Document Object Model) in your javascript.
i.e :

```
<script>
var foo = document.getElementById('blah');
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="blah" />
</body>
```

i hope my answer can help